# Need help with static / non-static members

Tags: c++, fltk

I have a static member function that looks like this:

```
void whackamole_window::showmole(void *){
  if (mtime == 0) {
    Fl::remove_timeout(whackamole_window::showmole);
  }
  else {
    //...

    m(Point(randx*50+25,randy*50+25),randval),
    mb(Point(randx*50,randy*50),50,50,"1",cb_addscore)

    Fl::check();
    Fl::redraw();

    mtime -= 3;
    Fl::repeat_timeout(3, whackamole_window::showmole);
    return;
  }
}
```

The member function is defined as the following in the class

```
static void showmole(void*);
```

Since static members can't access any other members of the class (except for other static members), I'm getting the following error:

> mole111j.cpp:176: invalid use of
>   member `whackamole_window::m' in
>   static member function
>   mole111j.cpp:177: invalid use of
>   member`whackamole_window::mb' in
>   static    member function

The timer doesn't seem to work if I try to make the function non-static. So how can I work around this and access the m and mb members using the timer?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about FLTK, but it looks like your `showMole()` method gets a `void *` value passed in, which you can presumably specify when you arm the timer.

If you provide a pointer to the window when you arm the timer, you can cast the `void *` value back to `whackamole_window *` and use the resulting pointer to access non-static members.

Comment: Excuse my newbieness, but how do I do all that? I sort of know how to use pointers but I don't understand what you mean by casting void * back

Comment: `whackamole_window *thisWindow = (whackamole_window *) argPtr;` - where argPtr is the void * that was passed in to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Are m and mb both static variables? If not you can't use them in a static function like you are.

Make them static or pass them in.

Comment: They are non-static variables. how can I "pass them in"?